# Android Studio unable to resolve method in class

Tags: java, android, class

I am trying to make a basic connect 3 app as part of a course challenge.
The problem I am having is that I am unable to access the methods inside the class `Players` in order to set which buttons have been pressed by which players: `Cannot resolve method 'noughtsPlayer'`.

I created an instance of `Players` on the `onCreate` method and declared it at the top of the script. That instance itself is recognised but for some reason the contained methods, `noughtsPlayer` and `crossesPlayer` are not.

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.richardcurteis.connect3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public boolean noughtsTurn;
    ArrayList board;
    String players;

    public void receiveClick(View view) {
        String buttonPressed = (String) view.getTag();
        board.remove(buttonPressed);

        if (view instanceof Button) {
            Button B = (Button) view;
            B.setText(noughtsTurn ? players.noughtsPlayer() : players.crossesPlayer());
        }

    }

    class Players {
        public String noughtsPlayer() { return "O"; }
        public String crossesPlayer() { return "X"; }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        boolean noughtsTurn = true;
        board = new ArrayList();
        for (int x = 0; x < getBoardSize(); x++) {
            String y = String.valueOf(x);
            board.add(y);
        }
        Players players = new Players();

    }

    public int getBoardSize() {
        int buttonCount = 0;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button) {
                        buttonCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return buttonCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have global variable `String players` and local variable `Players players`.
This is problem.
And class String doesn't have those methods.
To solve this problem change `String players;` to `Players players;`
and         `Players players = new Players();` to     `players = new Players();`

Comment: Ah right. I had it in my head that as it was returning a string I should mark it as such. Obviously not!
Thanks

Comment: Have you solved your problem? You can accept answer to help other people with similar problems if you want.

Comment: Yeah I did, I had to wait a few minutes till I was allowed to mark it as solved